PHPUnit with Xdebug on a Laravel modularized project not showing source code coverage for modules
I'm working on a Laravel 10 (with PHPUnit 10 and Xdebug 3) project in which business logic has been split into modules: at the app/ directory level is the modules/ directory where resides modules code (i.e. providers, migrations, models, etc).
.
├── app          <-
├── bin
├── bootstrap
├── config
├── database
├── docker
├── environments
├── lang
├── modules      <-
├── node_modules
├── public
├── resources
├── routes
├── storage
├── tests
└── vendor

In phpunit.xml I added the new directory source as follow:
<source>
    <include>
        <directory>app</directory>
        <directory>modules</directory>
    </include>
</source>

So now the HTML code coverage output correctly list it:

Problem is: its coverage is always at 0% when running tests for modules business logic.
I never used PHPUnit code coverage attributes since I never needed them, every other project I worked on generated correct code coverage without them.
Do I need to add those attributes for source files out of app/ directory?
Update #1
Adding CoversClass(TestedClass::class)] attribute to a module test class did not solve the problem, modules/ code coverage percentage is still 0.
Update #2: Xdebug not being set to coverage
I'm checking if Xdebug mode is correctly set to coverage during tests, and using a simple dd(getenv()) inside of a test show that XDEBUG_MODE=off.
The application is running on docker and the container mount a custom 99-php.ini with the entry xdebug.mode=coverage, so I assume that the '99' makes it the least important between the .ini files being loaded, thus its config do not overwrite an existing xdebug.mode=off in another file.
I added the entry <env name="XDEBUG_MODE" value="coverage" /> to phpunix.xml php section, but still the test output still show off as xdebug mode.
Finally I tried to manually set env variable in container with XDEBUG_MODE=coverage and it looks working (test output correctly display an entry XDEBUG_MODE=coverage from getenv()), problem is modules directory still get a 0% code coverage.

have u try like ./app  and ./modules? ref docs

@francisco I don't get what you mean, testing configuration already include app and modules paths, as I said html output correctly list every subfolder and file in both, moreover for app is reported the percentage for the little amount of code covered

Sorry, try this php -d pcov.enabled=1 -d pcov.directory=. -dpcov.exclude="~vendor~" \   vendor/bin/pest --coverage-html=build/coverage I've seen here ref they have a case with 0% cov

and one more thing, do you have extension=pcov enable in PHP? it's better that xdebug

my bad, I forgot to tell I'm using xdebug, sorry; i know pcov is faster on line coverage, but xdebug can do more stuff; moreover, looking at pcov github page it looks unmaintained right now since the most recent edit on a file is 9 months old, with an average of 3ys and an oldest of 6ys...

and did the command worked? any more error or still 0%?

The numbers in these files (99) are the order. So a 99 file will override a 20 file.

I have the exact same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79222614/why-does-code-coverage-for-custom-modules-fail-in-laravel?noredirect=1#comment139700958_79222614
Regarding the xdebug.mode, there is actually a bug in Laravel, SAIL_XDEBU_MODE has no effect, I explained this in that article: https://medium.com/@iwasherefirst2/how-to-set-up-xdebug-with-laravel-sail-a-complete-guide-98d6498b382a - but I don"t think its an issue for you because if xdebug.mode is not set to  coverage you should not be able to create a coverage report at all

I encountered the same issue, and the root cause is related to PCOV. It cannot handle a situation where you have more than two directories at the root level.
Your phpunit.xml configuration is correct, so there's no need to change it. The issue can be resolved by simply disabling PCOV during the code coverage run. You can do this by using the following command:
sail php -d pcov.enabled=0 ./vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-html coverage-report

This ensures that PCOV does not interfere with your code coverage and allows your configuration to work as expected.
For more details, you can check Why Does Code Coverage for Custom Modules Fail in Laravel?
