Why Does Code Coverage for Custom Modules Fail in Laravel?
I set up PHPUnit to work with two different namespaces in a non-Laravel project, and it works perfectly. This is the folder structure of my working example:
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── composer.json
├── phpunit.xml
├── app/
│   └── Example.php
├── modules/
│   └── Example.php
└── tests/
    ├── AppTest.php
    └── ModulesTest.php

In this setup, phpunit.xml looks like this:
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Tests">
        <directory>tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
<source>
    <include>
        <directory>app</directory>
        <directory>modules</directory>
    </include>
</source>

And the namespaces are defined in composer.json as follows:
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Modules\\": "modules/"
    }
}

I run the following command to generate the coverage report:
docker compose exec php ./vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-html coverage-report

In this non-Laravel example, the code coverage report correctly shows both app and modules namespaces covered by tests.

You can checkout the full repository of my example at https://github.com/iwasherefirst2/poc-coverage
The Issue in Laravel:
When I replicate this setup in a fresh Laravel 10.48.24 project, with the same structure and configuration, the coverage report fails to include the modules folder, even though the tests for it pass successfully.

Here is the Laravel-specific information:

Laravel Version: 10.48.24
PHP Version: 8.2.26
PHPUnit Version: 10.x (same in both projects)

Both projects use the same PHPUnit version, and the tests in Laravel are plain unit tests (use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase). However, the coverage report for my Laravel app only includes the app namespace, completely omitting modules.
Here is also the full repository to look at https://github.com/iwasherefirst2/poc-laravel-coverage-modules
What I Tried:

Ensured the namespace configuration in composer.json is correct and ran composer dump-autoload.
Used the same phpunit.xml structure in both projects.
Verified that tests for the modules folder run successfully in Laravel.

Key Observations:

The Laravel project is identical to the working example, except for the additional Laravel-specific files and dependencies.
Despite this, the coverage report excludes the modules namespace in my Laravel app, but not in my simple php app.

Question:
Why does the PHPUnit code coverage report fail to include the modules namespace in Laravel, even though the tests are running and passing? Could this be related to Laravel’s PHPUnit integration or autoload configuration? How can I resolve this and ensure full coverage for both namespaces in Laravel?

I remember seeing something similar a few weeks ago, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79114026/phpunit-with-xdebug-on-a-laravel-modularized-project-not-showing-source-code-cov, it is not the same issue, but he ends up having the same issue as you do, 0% on your modules. What happens if you open one file from the report inside the modules folder? What do you see? And 2 tests, do you have your xdebug set to coverage? and what happens if you move the modules folder to another name, for example myWorkingDirectory and try again (same for namespace)?

@matiaslauriti Thanks for pointing me to the related question; it’s helpful to compare! Regarding your suggestion: what exactly do you mean by "opening a report from the modules folder"? The coverage report is generated at the root level, and it doesn’t seem to include files from inside the modules folder.
As for Xdebug, I have xdebug.mode configured as develop, debug, coverage, without there would be no coverage-report. Unfortunately, renaming the modules folder and updating the namespace accordingly didn’t resolve the issue. Any other thoughts or troubleshooting steps you’d recommend?

Yes! I meant you to open the folder and see what files shows there and if you open one, if you truly see their lines are not marked or anything, but it is worse, you don't have files at all, right? Give me some time and I will come up with something for you to test

After thorough investigation, I identified that the difference between the Laravel repository and the non-Laravel repository was the use of PCOV during code coverage in the Laravel setup, while the non-Laravel repository relied on Xdebug.


The Issue with PCOV
PCOV appears to have issues handling code coverage for multiple directories at the root level. This caused the modules directory to be excluded from the coverage report in the Laravel repository.
The Fix
To resolve this issue, you can disable PCOV and use Xdebug.
Option 1: Remove PCOV
Modify your Dockerfile to exclude PCOV entirely. Simply remove the php8.2-pcov package from the installation step:
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    php8.2-cli \
    php8.2-xdebug \
    ...
    # Remove php8.2-pcov or don't include it at all

Option 2: Manually Disable PCOV
If removing PCOV is not an option, you can manually disable it during the coverage run by passing the pcov.enabled=0 directive:
sail php -d pcov.enabled=0 ./vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-text

PHPUnit XML Configuration
Ensure your phpunit.xml file includes the appropriate configuration for code coverage, depending on your PHPUnit version.
For PHPUnit 9:
Use the <filter> tag with a <whitelist> section:
<filter>
    <whitelist>
        <directory suffix=".php">app</directory>
        <directory suffix=".php">modules</directory>
    </whitelist>
</filter>

For PHPUnit 10:
Switch to the <source> tag with <include>:
<source>
    <include>
        <directory suffix=".php">app</directory>
        <directory suffix=".php">modules</directory>
    </include>
</source>

